# Trying to add a button to this script so it will generate the numbers on click. Also I dont want the numbers to ever repeat in the same order

Tags: javascript, html, web, button

Trying to add a button to this script so it will generate the numbers on click. Also I dont want the numbers to ever repeat in the same order. Im doing this inside of sqaurespace as well.

We are trying to come up with a way to give our users a unique ID for raffles from clicking this button.

Any help is really appreciated

**HTML:**

```html
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Unique ID</h2>
    
    <p id="array_number" style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center;"></p>
    <input id="Generate" type="button" value="Generate" onclick="();" />
```

**Javascript:**

```js
    var min = 1;
    var max = 90;
    //Number of numbers to extract
    var stop = 6;
    
    var numbers = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
      var n =  Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
      var check = numbers.includes(n);
      
      if(check === false) {
        numbers.push(n);
      } else {
        while(check === true){
          n = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
          check = numbers.includes(n);
            if(check === false){
              numbers.push(n);
            }
         }
      }
    }
    
    sort();
    
    //Sort the array in ascending order
    function sort() {
      numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
      document.getElementById("array_number").innerHTML = numbers.join(" - ");
    }
```

Comment: You want a total of 6 random numbers generated on click each time you click the button? Sort of like a lottery number?

Comment: do you expect all id's to be determined at one time in a single client or is this to be used by multiple users?

Comment: Yes we are trying to make it generate the random numbers on click for every different user. @date landry exactly like a lottery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modified a bit

```js
// Get DOM
var button = document.querySelector('#Generate');

// I put most of your code into one function
function GenerateRandomNums() {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 90;
  var stop = 6;

  var numbers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    var check = numbers.includes(n);

    if (check === false) {
      numbers.push(n);
    } else {
      while (check === true) {
        n = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
        check = numbers.includes(n);
        if (check === false) {
          numbers.push(n);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  document.getElementById("array_number").innerHTML = numbers.join(" - ");

  return numbers;
}

// When the button is clicked, the function is executed
button.addEventListener('click', GenerateRandomNums);
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Unique ID</h2>

<p id="array_number" style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center;"></p>

<!-- Removed onClick -->
<input id="Generate" type="button" value="Generate" />
```

---

#### Refactored

```js
// GET THE BUTTON
const button = document.querySelector('#generate-button');

// GENERATE A RANDOM NUMBER FUNCTION
// I made a function for a random number that can be used in other functions
// Defaut min = 1, max = 90
function generateRandomNumber(min = 1, max = 90) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

// CREATE UNIQUE IDS FUNCTION
function createUniqueIds(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Get the <p>
  const uniqueIds = document.querySelector('#unique-ids');
  
  // Create an array with 6 empty elements
  let ids = Array(6);
  let n;

  // For loop that iterates up to the length of the array (6 times)
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    do {
      n = generateRandomNumber();
    } while (ids.includes(n));

    ids[i] = n;
  }

  // Sort and join the array
  let numString = ids.sort((a, b) => a - b).join(' - ');
  
  // Update the text inside of the <p>
  uniqueIds.textContent = numString;
}

// CLICK EVENT
// When the button is clicked, createUniqueIds() is executed
button.addEventListener('click', createUniqueIds, false);
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Unique ID</h2>

<p id="unique-ids" style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center;">Loading...</p>
<input id="generate-button" type="button" value="Generate" />
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much this was a huge help. Just out of curiosity how would you go about being able to keep track of the random numbers that have been generated? For now we are having it be sent back to us but we want to be able to automate the process.

Comment: I'm glad to be of service. There are some options: MySQL with PHP, Google Spreadsheet with GAS, Firebase with JS etc. In my opinion, GAS is one of the easiest. Firebase is the most professional and modern among my examples.